# How to check if element of array is int or float?

Tags: c, arrays

I have 2 arrays, one is commented, I would like to make universal printf that will plot the values:

```
int values [] = { 88, 56, 100, 2, 25 };
//float values[] = {88.5f, 56.5f, 100.0f, 2.234f, 88.12f};

if (value[0] is int) {
    for(i; i < 5; ++i)
    printf("%d ", *(values + i));
} else {
    for(i; i < 5; ++i)
    printf("%f ", *(values + i));
}
```

Is there any way to check it? For example when I wanted to see if element is char or int then I used sizeof

Comment: Yes I know. But I need to do program for classes. Ill comment the int values and uncomment float values then start program, then Ill comment float and uncomment int. Those arrays are used for sorting.

Comment: I dont need a way to store 2 value types in one. I need info how to find out if the element of array is int or float.

Comment: You are probably trying to do the wrong thing. This said, you can use in the latest C standard, `_Generic(values[0], int: 0, float:1, default:2)`

Comment: _Generic(values[0], int: 0, float:1, default: 2); thats interesting but won't compile. I'm latest Dev-C++ 5.5.3 currently. [Error] expected expression before 'int'

Comment: @F1sher If you have the option of using recent GCC or Clang versions, both have already implemented `_Generic`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I didn't know about `_Generic`, thanks!

Comment: You forgot to initialize `i` to `0`. And why are you using `*(values + i)` rather than `values[i]`?

Comment: I don't know if you noticed it but Marian V and I have completely solved your problem with only one minor drawback: you need to include the standard header `limits.h` from your system. After that, `#define IS_INT_TYPE(x) ((x) >= INT_MIN && (x) <= INT_MAX && ((x)*0+1)/2 == 0)` returns `1` only if `x` is an `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the caveat that this is a lot of sophistication for a “feature” that you are only going to use while debugging your program, you can use C11's `_Generic` construct:

```
_Generic(values[0], int: 0, float:1, default:2)
```

What you should probably do instead that would be more consistent with your intentions is conditional compilation:

```
#define FLOAT_CASE

#ifdef FLOAT_CASE
float values[] = {88.5f, 56.5f, 100.0f, 2.234f, 88.12f};
#else
int values [] = { 88, 56, 100, 2, 25 };
#endif

... // all the code that is independent of the type of values here

for(i; i < 5; ++i)
#ifdef FLOAT_CASE
  printf("%f ", *(values + i));
#else
  printf("%d ", *(values + i));
#endif
```

Comment: Why do you write `*(value + i)` rather than `values[i]`? And you forgot to initialize `i` to `0`.

Comment: @KeithThompson You should direct all these remarks to the OP. I took program lines verbatim from the question to make it clear that my answer was to use `#ifdef` or `_Generic`, not to fix stylistic issues (that wouldn't help with the problem of writing generic code for `int` and `float`)

Answer (score 2):

An ugly solution: if you only need to distinct between int and float you can assign a non-integer value, say 0.1 to the variable and then test the actual value. This gives something like:

```
#define IS_INT_TYPE(x) (x=0.1, x==0)
```

However, this will destroy the original value of the macro parameter. If you use gcc, you can use typeof() extension to cast the value:

```
#define IS_INT_TYPE(x) (((typeof(x)) 0.1) == 0)
```

And Pascal's notes gave me the idea to the solution:

```
#define IS_INT_TYPE(x) (((x*0+1)/2) == 0)
```

Comment: If you want to go in this direction, a solution if one knows that `x` is neither `0` nor within a factor of two of the limits of its type is `x / (x + x) == 0`

Comment: Removing the limitation for 0: `x==0 ? ((x+1) / 2 == 0) : …`

Comment: Only requiring `x`, if `float`, to be finite: `x == 0 ? ((x+1) / 2 == 0) : (x/x) / (x/x + x/x) == 0`. [after seeing edit] Well, okay, your solution is clearly better but still requires `x` to be finite. This is easy to test: `!(x < INT_MIN) && !(x > INT_MAX) && …`